# Issue in accessing the value of final variable after changing it by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
 class FinalConcept
 {
   private final int number = 22;


   public static void main(String args[])
    { 
          try{
        FinalConcept obj  = new FinalConcept();      
        System.out.println("value of the x variable "+obj.number);


       Field obj1 = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("number");
        obj1.setAccessible(true);
         obj1.setInt(obj,45);
```

If I try to access the variable by field function then I get changed value

```
System.out.println("value of the x variable "+obj1.get(obj));//45
```

But if I try to access by the name of variable, I get the same value

```
System.out.println("value of x varialbe "+obj.x);//22
```

Why is this hapenning ?

Comment: Possible Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection

Comment: I suspect that `x` just becomes a compile-time constant and directly inlined.  But seriously, _why_ are you screwing with final variables like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable in number is declared final, so it can't be modified. The object itself will keep always the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Its interesting, I tried to dig it out, and found one observation, If we change the filed "number" from *int* to *Integer*, then we get the exception:

Exception->  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final java.lang.Integer field HelloTestJava.number to (int)45`

One reason which I observed is that, this behavior is with primitives (int, char, byte , short, boolean, float, double, long) only. There is no exception If we try to change the value of a final primitive field through the Field object.

The same exception I got when I take a final Boolean field and tried to change it through reflection(i.e. through Field object)

```
Exception->  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final java.lang.Boolean field HelloTestJava.number to (boolean)false
```

But one thing is for sure, that your object will always have the correct(not-changed) value, doesn't matter we are trying to modify the value through reflection.